# How can i modify this query to leave out blanks or empty value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This query is used to select distinct value from a table in the database

```
public List<SubDepartmentViewModel> GetSubDepartments()
{
    var query = _db.SendersReceivers.Select(a => new SubDepartmentViewModel
    {
        SubDepartmentName = a.SubDepartment //column in the database  
    })
    .Distinct().ToList();

    return query;
}
```

Comment: I would put the blank check before the Distinct(). Propably next to the `SubDepartmentName = a.SubDepartment` check. Otherwise I have not enough knowledge on LINQ to SQL to help.

Comment: blank or empty value on what basis? on  any specific column?

Comment: something like `.Where(a => a.SubDepartment != null && a.SubDepartment != string.Empty)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = _db.SendersReceivers
         .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.SubDepartment))
         .Select(a => new SubDepartmentViewModel
                {
                  SubDepartmentName = a.SubDepartment

                })
         .Distinct().ToList();
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I didn't think that `IsNullOrEmpty` could translate to SQL, are you sure that works?

Comment: It works. Below link lists all the unspported methods for System.String;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/system-string-methods?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: That's Linq to Sql, not Linq to Entities, and support for various operations varies by provider. I believe you would have to put your Where clause after the Select so that it operates locally instead of at the data store.